# Richedit control display the content of a string in winAPI c++ app

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, richedit

I have a richedit control on a dialog. I want to populate the richedit control with a string. The richedit control itself displays properly. But I don't know how to populate the richedit control with a string. I took a guess at it below, in the resource.rc code.

In main.cpp, I have:

```
case IDC_BUT_ABOUT:
            {
                HINSTANCE   hRichEdit;  
                hRichEdit = LoadLibrary("RICHED32.DLL"); 
                DialogBox( hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUT), hDlgWnd,(DLGPROC)InitAbout );
                //ShowWindow(hDlgWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL); 
                return TRUE;
            }
            break;
```

In resource.rc, I have:

```
IDD_ABOUT DIALOGEX 0, 0, 206, 136
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Close",IDCANCEL,77,115,50,14
    CONTROL         "",IDC_RICHEDIT21,"RichEdit20W",ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,36,53,130,46
END

string rt  = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0     Arial;}{\f1\fnil\fprq2\fcharset0 Biondi;}}{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20\par\cf1\f1 hello\cf0\f0  \ul some text here\par}";

this.IDC_RICHEDIT21.Rtf = rt;
```

But this apparently isn't even close to how I should put text from a string into a rich edit control?

Comment: Back to basics I think. Why don't you learn how to do an edit control first and then progress to the more complex rich edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [EM_SETTEXTEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774284%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [EM_STREAMIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774302%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).